# Profile picture alignment problem

Tags: php, css, alignment

I have a page where it displays user profile data.

I've aligned the fields using the following code,

```
<h4><div class='holder'><span class='plabel'>Name</span> <span class='values'>: $name</span></div></h4><br />
```

The corresponding css is,

```
.holder {
width:700px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.plabel {
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width:150px;
}

.values {
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
width:550px;
float:right;
}
```

Now I'm tring to add a profile image to the right side of profile data as follows,

Name :

Age :                 pic here >

etc....

I tried using the following code before name,

```
<span class='ppic'><img src='$url' alt='Profile Pic' /></span>
```

with css,

```
.ppic {
width:200px;
float:right;
}
```

It is aligned to right but the name , etc goes down as if i've inserted line break.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the image to stay on right side, you can try this instead of float:

```
.ppic {
width:200px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to make the parent container `position: relative;`. If you don't, your image will stick to the side of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS for that element (`.ppic`):

```
display: inline-block;
```

Or make it a `<div>`.